# "Error: you must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined."

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm getting this error message: "Error: you must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined." even though I am passing the Trades component to connect. Here's my container component:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getAllTrades} from '@src/state';

import Trades from './index'; //presentational component
import routes from '../../routes';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    snapshot: getAllTrades(state),
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, {navigation}) => {
  return {
    test: snapshot => {
      dispatch(getAllTrades(snapshot));
      navigation.navigate(routes.trades.name);
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Trades);
```

and here is my presentational component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {Center, Text} from '@src/components';
import routes from '@src/routes';
import {createPrimaryHeaderOptions} from '@src/navigation';
import TradesContainer from './trades.container';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Content = () => {
  return (
    <Center>
      <Text>Trades Screen</Text>
    </Center>
  );
};

const Trades = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name={routes.trades.name}
        component={Content}
        options={createPrimaryHeaderOptions({title: routes.trades.title})}
      />
      {/* <Stack.Screen name="test" component={TradesContainer} /> */}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Trades;
```

Comment: What files are these two components in? It looks like you might actually have a circular import problem here.

Comment: @markerikson You're right. Even though I wasn't using it, I must have imported it without thinking and just by removing the import statement, the error disappeared. Thanks!